# How to calculate (a*b*c*d/e)%m f a,b,c,d,e are of order 10^18?

Tags: c, algorithm

I want to calculate `(a*b*c*d/e)%m` where my `a,b,c,d,e` are of order `10^18` . `e` perfectly divides `a*b*c*d`. The problem is that I cannot multiply them, as I won't be able to store them as they would be of the range(10^72). Again, I can't take modulus first either? What should I do?

Comment: Why can’t you take the modulus first?

Comment: @StephenCanon I think I can't take the modulus first as (a/b)modc is not equal to (a mod c)/(b mod c)

Comment: @Kevin switching to python isn't an option for me. :)

Comment: @user3868494: But `a/b` is equivalent to `a*(1/b)` and `(a*c)%m == ((a%m)*(c%m))%m`.

Comment: @JoelCornett `1/b` is not an integer, and the equality `(a*c)%m == ((a%m)*(c%m))%m` only makes sense when `a` and `c` are integers. What you said can be made correct by taking the multiplicative inverse of `b` modulo `m`, but that may not exist and is not simple to calculate.

Comment: what is the size of `m`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the modular arithmetic properties and that `e` divide `a*b*c*d`. Also assuming that `m*m` don't overflow in the type of data used.

As [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) state:

if `a1 = b1 mod n` and `a2 = b2 mod n` then:

```
a1 + a2 = b1 + b2 mod n
a1 - a2 = b1 - b2 mod n
a1 * a2 = b1 * b2 mod n
```

The **division** is not here. By this you could **not** use: `((a%m)*(b%m)*(c%m)*(d%m)/(e%m))%m`

Code.

```
gcd_value = gcd(a, e);
result = (a / gcd_value) % m;
e /= gcd_value;
gcd_value = gcd(b, e);
result *= (b / gcd_value) % m;
e /= gcd_value;
gcd_value = gcd(c, e);
result *= (c / gcd_value) % m;
e /= gcd_value;
gcd_value = gcd(d, e);
result *= (d / gcd_value) % m;
result = result % m;
```